# How to edit random numbers in a txt file using batch

Tags: batch-file

Hello guys I need a bit of help

I am trying to edit a txt file but it has no data in front of it so I am having a hard tle

Here is my script

```bash
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd /d "%~dp0"

set "Mfind=    %Random%"

@For %%G In ("%~dp03Ready\NSB") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp03Ready\NSBEdited") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

Set /p "FPats=Enter Your Amount: 

FOR /f "dedestination directory
 SET "newdest=%%~dpq"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:%sourcedir%=%destdir%!"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:~0,-1!"
 MD "!newdest!" 2>nul

(
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line IF "%%b" neq
 )
)>"!newdest!\%%~nxq" 

)
GOTO :NSBEditing

:nidC1
SET "line=%line:-=%"
SET "original=line%" goto nidC1
set "line=!line:%Mfind%=%Mfind%%FPats%!"
GOTO :eof
```

Here is my txt file The text file cna reacll part of it<b
"upnn": 0,
"upfb": true,
"upcu": {
"adi
"isnc": false,
"erpm": 0
}
},
58, < ---------------- Trying to edit these numbers
{
"upma":ue,
"upcu": {
"adid": "lphaSixoSSC
"adtc": [
{
"kfti": 1000.0,
"kfva": 0.321
}

Comment: What are you trying to replace the numbers from / to. Should all those numbers be changed, or just some. Are they all being changed to the same value, or is the number to be changed on some unspecified basis?

Comment: Another question, Do those lines only have numbers, or have you edited out trailing data to mark their location? - One has a trailing `,` while the other doesn't

Comment: using batch for editing would be painful. Just use powershell, if this is a json file then it even has direct support via [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.3), [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.3) and similar

Comment: When you treat a JSON file just as a text file, you risk deteriorating its format. To avoid that, you should better use a language that natively supports JSON…

Answer (score 0):

The below function can be used to modify lines containing only whitespace numbers and ','
 indicates a manditory argument, argument positions are fixed.

It uses a flag to mark line as being a number only - a For /f loop with delims overides the flag if the line is not empty after removing those delims.

```bat
@Echo off

:ReplaceNum <inputfilepath.ext> <outputfilepath.ext>
    Set "ScriptName=%~0"
    For /f "tokens=1,2* Delims=:" %%G in (":.%ScriptName%")Do If "%%G"=="." Set "ScriptName=Call :%%H"
    If "%~1"=="" (
        Echo(%ScriptName% ^<inputfilepath.ext^> ^<outputfilepath.ext^>
        Exit /B 0
    )

    %= Error 1; No Source =%            If not Exist "%~1" Exit /B 1
    %= Error 2; Filepaths Same =%       If "%~1"=="%~2" Exit /B 2

    Set "Class="
    1>"%~2" (
        For /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%~1")Do (
            Set "Line=%%G"
            Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            Set "isnum=true"
            For /f "delims=0123456789, " %%i in ("!Line!")Do Set "isnum=false"
            If "!isnum!"=="true" (
                Set "nLine=!Line: =!"
                Set "nLine=!nLine:,=!"
                Mode 120,40
                1> Con Call :GetNum Replace number:'!nLine!' for Class: !Class!
                For /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in ("!nLine! !Num!")Do Echo(!Line:%%i=%%j!
                Set "Class="
            )Else (
                Set ^"cLine=!Line:"=!"
                For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:," %%u in ("!Line!")Do If not "%%~b"=="" Set "Class=!Class! %%u"
                For %%c in ("{" "}" "[" "]") Do Set "Class=!Class:%%~c=!"
                For /L %%i in (1 1 4)Do Set "Class=!Class:  = !"
                Echo(!Line!
            )
            For /F "Delims=" %%c in ("!Class!")Do Endlocal & Set "Class=%%c"
        )
    )

Exit /B 0

:GetNum
(   Set LF=^


%= Linefeed Definition - Do not modify =%)
    Set "Num="
    Set /P "Num=%*!LF!>:"
    2> nul Set /A "Num+=0","1/Num" || Goto:GetNum
Exit /B 0
```

Comment: Functions are `call`ed. This functin returns help output if `Call`ed without arguments.
Using `Call:ReplaceNum sourceFile.ext destFile.ext Integer` will replace all instances of lines in sourceFile 'Arg1' containing numbers with the provided number 'Arg3' and output to destFile 'Arg2'. If you wish replace each number seperately, you'll need to modify the function to take input for the number to insert instead of using %3.

Replacing an integer trailing a value key is a different task again, and would need a defferent set of tests to isolate the desired key / value pairing.

Comment: I've modified the function to take input for each number to be replaced. Run it from the command line with 2 Arguments: SourceFilepath.ext OutputFilepath.ext

Comment: It is the same as any batch gile or function that is called with arguments. You acn place the function in an existing batch script or use the script as a stand alone by running it in an open cmd.exe window. Surely you understand the use of arguments, or can search the usage of  Call

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here we go (again)...

*First step*: (trying to) identify the lines to be edited:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "last=1"
set "lines=:"
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "{ } ]" (09)Fus.txt') do (
   set /A "prev=%%a-2, line=%%a-1"
   if !prev! equ !last! set "lines=!lines!!line!:"
   set "last=%%a"
)

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" (09)Fus.txt') do (
   if "!lines::%%a:=!" neq "%lines%" (
      echo %%b   ^< - This line will be edited
   ) else (
      echo %%b
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
    "cpup": [
    {
      "upma": "id",
      "upnn": 0,
      "upfb": true,
      "upcu": {
        "adid": "Dge_ChngerSTemon_2018_nit2",
        "ulid": "TT_UPADE_NROU03",
        "upty": "NOUS",
        "isnc": false,
        "erpm": 0
      }
    },
    58,   < - This line will be edited
    {
      "upma": "id",
      "upnn": 0,
      "upfb": true,
      "upcu": {
        "adid": "lphaSixoSSCrewcycled_016_tur1",
        "ulid": "TT_RADE_TUO02",
        "upty": "BO",
        "uplv": 1,
        "erpm": 0,
        "adtc": [
          {
            "kfti": 1000.0,
            "kfva": 0.321
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    70   < - This line will be edited
  ],
```